# Need info on why I have HTP.P on my PL/SQL code,,, if APEX is not involved...?

Tags: oracle, scala, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I am writing Scala code to access oracle 12 c.I have PLSQL stored procedure with a line saying  (HTP.P (r1.id||r1.name); ). Earlier it used to be a code for apex,do I still need it in my Scala build. if apex is out of the picture.please give some thoughts,thanks.

Comment: Please see [mcve]. As worded, it's impossible for anyone to understand what you're doing and what might be happening.

Comment: If the client doesn't use the web output then it'll do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle Web Toolkit / [mod_plsql](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/webtier/HSADM/under_mods.htm#HSADM003) predates Apex, so it's possible that your procedure is used by something other than the Apex application. To be honest, I'm not sure how you would check though.